# Hide URL parameters and read them

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url, parameters

Is there any method to hide URL parameters and then read the hidden parameters with code? For example I have this in my page:
"example.com/transaction.html?price=10".

I have tried to encode with Base64, but it doesn't work as expected (encoding works, decoding not), so I want to hide either the price=10 or transaction.html?price=10.

I heard that AngularJS could hide parameters, but can it read "hidden" parameters or how does it work?

Thanks in advance!

```
function getUrlVar() {
    var result = {};
    var location = window.location.href.split('#');
    var parts = location[0].replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m,key,value) {
        result [key] = value;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to read the parameters on the server or the client?

Comment: From the client I believe

Comment: you should provide a jsfiddle or something similar so we can help you.

Comment: or you can just hash the `price=10` to make it meanless to a user but your server will be able to de-hash and understand it (or your client side js will hash/de-hash too)?

Comment: can i ask for your scenario? do you have a products which has a `price`? if answer is yes the product has `id`?

Comment: How do I hash it? And yes, my product has a price like this <span id="totalPrice7">
       <script>
        getPrice(9,"totalPrice7")
       </script>
      </span> and yeah, there's and id as well. Encoding works, but not decoding.

Comment: by hide url parameters you mean that your website address should still look like `www.something.com` but still the data is loaded or when you are fetching the data the address should be encoded that no one is able to understand ?

Comment: please, provide your current working example on a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net and edit your original answer with the URL, so we can see what you are doing and help you easily.

Comment: I would like to hide the price=10 from the url, it could look like example.com/transaction.html but without the ?price=10. And @JVLobo, I do not have a working example of hiding the parameter, the decoding just does not work and I've been thinking about to use another method. Basically I tried this: a.href = "transaction.html?" + btoa("price=50"); <- This works, but decoding does not: var finalPrice = atob(getUrlVar()["price"] * basePrice);

Comment: you have something then... to get some help would be easier for the people here to have that on a fiddle or at least well formatted on your original question

Comment: Yes, I do have encoding with Base64. Simply btoa(variable) and atob(method) and it does not work. Now I want a methot that HIDES the url parameters, not encode

Comment: that's the thing... you have code that you haven't posted. You have a getUrlVar() function that we don't know what it does... thats why I told you to provide as with the code you're using

Comment: @Timppa What you're asking makes absolutely no sense to me.  Are you talking about making an HTTP POST request with form data?  Are you talking about encrypting the query string? Are you talking about signing the query string so that it can't be readily modified?

Comment: I answered something for you... not sure if that's what you need, but there you have it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to show the query parameters to the users in the address bar, you can easily achieve it using Javascript or jquery also need to switch to angular just for this.

What you can do is instead of using `<a href = ....> </a>`  to fetch the data for that query which will redirect the user to the link say  `www.something.com?price=10` instead of this what you can do is use a button as

`<button type="button" onclick="fetch()">Fetch Data</button>`

and in your Javascript file you can make a `GET or POST` request in this way these parameters you want to hide won't be shown, it's just these will be send to the server in background without changing your address.

To make this `GET Request` you can do something like assuming you are sending the data from a text field :

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "www.something.com/",
          data: {
            price: $("#price")
          },
          success: function(data) {
            // do something with the data you received}
          });
      })
```

```html
<input type=text id="price" />
<button id="button">Send</button>
```

Now you got the data in background without showing the parameters to the user in their address bar.

Comment: This will hide the parameters from url but not from network, yes? If one monitors the network, he/she will see the get/post call, no?

Comment: Yes correct, if someone is reading the network tab there is no other way to hide Paramus except to encrypt it before sending them.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS passes the params by using $urlRouterProvider,
[AngularJS $urlRouterProvider](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider)

Your parameters is included like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('toState', {
  url: /your-url
  templateUrl:'wokka.html',
  controller:'stateController',
  params: {
  'referer': 'some default', 
'param2': 'some default', 
'etc': 'some default'
}
});
```

and your parameter isn't included in link, you could run $state.go function with your parameters in the controller.

But i also think that AngularJS using Ajax mechanism  so actually, it doesn't mean the page is reloaded, just url and js, html is loaded

It is just the angularJs way and maynot your need.
I found the link can be useful:
[Code-project how to hide parameters in url](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/158919/how-to-hide-parameters-in-url)

Comment: Please improve your answer by `how can i get params from controller?`

Comment: By my way, i considered the "state" as a page when i change my link to new page. So, you can use $state.go('newState',{id: yourId}).
In your routing file, 
$stateProvider
  .state('newState', {
    url: "/new",<br/>
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    params: { id: null, },
   controller: newStateController
  }) 
and at the newStateController , inject $state and you can get the id by $state.params.id

Comment: Get item by id is more Logical than set params in the `state`, because it's more dynamic

Comment: in this question's case, i think that use POST method with params instead of GET because in generally, GET request isn't safe

Comment: I have never used AngularJS before so I am not really sure what that does and how to use it, however I will look up to your link

Answer (score 0):

I've created a snippet for you, I think something like that is what you are asking for.

I made it quick, so it'd need lot of improvement, but at least you got something to begin with:

```js
let paramsRaw = "price=10";
let urlEncoded = "example.com/transaction.html?" + btoa(paramsRaw);

function getUrlVar() {
  var location = urlEncoded; //window.location.href.split('#');
  var paramsEncoded = urlEncoded.split('?')[1];
  var paramsDecoded = atob(paramsEncoded);
  var paramsDecodedValue = paramsDecoded.split('=')[1];
  
  return parseInt(paramsDecodedValue);
}

let price = getUrlVar();

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = price * 50;
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

Take a look to that and let me know.

Cheers!